# How to initiate class property dynamically

Tags: java

I have the following stuff

```
String[] header1 = {"func", "name", "lrt"};
String[] value11 ={"f1", "n1", "0.1"};
String[] value12 ={"f2", "n2", "0.2"}; 
......

String[] header2 = {"name", "func", "lrt"};
String[] value21 ={"n3", "f3", "0.1"};
String[] value22 ={"n4", "f4", "0.2"}; 
......


class unit {
  String func;
  String name;
  double lrt;
}
```

I have more than 1000 groups of different headers (and their attached values) organized in different order.

how can I initiate the unit class with the property name matching different headers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use reflection ?

Comment: By the way `String[] value21 ={"n3", "f3", 0.1};` will not work as you have a `double` value in your `String` array.

Comment: Sounds like an appropriate use case for a `Map<String, String[][]>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use reflection for that it is actually quite easy:

```
unit u = new unit();
for(int i=0;i<;header1.lenght;i++) {
  String h = header1[i];
  String v = value11[i];
  Field f = u.getClass().getDeclaredField(h);
  f.set(u, v);
}
```

Obviously you will need some more infrastructure to iterate your data tuples ... value11, value12, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` would be a better approach to your implementation:

```
Map<String[], ArrayList<Object[]>> unit = new HashMap<String[], ArrayList<Object[]>>();

String[] header1 = {"func", "name", "lrt"};
Object[] value11 ={"f1", "n1", 0.1};
Object[] value12 ={"f2", "n2", 0.2}; 

String[] header2 = {"name", "func", "lrt"};
Object[] value21 ={"n3", "f3", 0.1};
Object[] value22 ={"n4", "f4", 0.2}; 

ArrayList<Object[]> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(value11);
values.add(value12);
unit.put(header1, values);

values.clear();
values.add(value21);
values.add(value22);
unit.put(header1, values);
```

Try this and you will have a `unit` object holding all your values.